# MailGun ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailgun

I'm getting an error when trying to send mail from my website I followed a tutorial on youtube.

Error occurs in index.js which is not even on my server at result.id:

```
  callback(null, { ...result, messageId: result.id });
} catch (error) {
    callback(error);
  }
};
```

Here is some of my code server.js:

```
    // email, subject, text
app.post('/email', (req, res) => {
    const { subject, email, text } = req.body;
    log('Data: ', req.body);

    sendMail(email, subject, text, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            log('ERROR: ', err);
            return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message || 'Internal Error' });
        }
        log('Email sent!!!');
        return res.json({ message: 'Email sent!!!!!' });
    });
});

// Render home page
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'));
});

// Error page
app.get('/error', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'error.html'));
});

// Email sent page
app.get('/email/sent', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'emailMessage.html'));
});

// Start server

app.get('/',(req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'contact.html'));
});
```

Here is contact.html:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" /> <br />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" /> <br />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <textarea name="text" class="form-control" id="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea> <br />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary"
                                    </div>
```

Please help in anyway you can this is the last step of the website as you can see it was done in node.js. I searched previous answers and was not able to find one that matched what I'm going through. I can't change the index.js file because it's not on my server.

Comment: Your subject and email fields at the form are missing the name attribute

Comment: I changed that and still not the error

Comment: The github of the tutorial: https://github.com/accimeesterlin/nodemailer-examples/tree/master/sendFormEmail

Comment: Did you do all the steps (1-3) provided at that github link?

Comment: Yes every step @ozgur